# How to select different count data based on certain condition in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a schema defined as :

TABLE A

```
+---------+---------+-----------+    
| ITEM_ID | TYPE_ID | DUE_DATE  |
+-------------------------------+
|     15  |      1  | 2018-01-2 |
|     15  |      2  | 2018-01-5 |
|     16  |      1  | 2018-01-2 |
|     16  |      1  | 2018-01-2 |
|     17  |      2  | 2018-01-23|
+-------------------------------+
```

The TYPE ID WILL ALWAYS BE EITHER 1 OR 2.

I want the count of transactions happened in TODAY, ONE WEEK AND ONE MONTH BASED ON TYPE.

THE OUTPUT SCHEMA THAT I WANT :

```
|ITEM_ID | COUNT_TODAY_TYPE_1 | COUNT_TODAY_TYPE_2 | COUNT_ONEWEEK_TYPE_1 | COUNT_ONEWEEK_TYPE_1 |
```

If there was no subtype, I could have achieved this by following

```
select typeid,
       sum(case when cast(due_date as date) = cast(getdate() as date) then 1 else 0 end) as today,
       sum(case when cast(due_date as date) >= cast(getdate() - 7 as date) then 1 else 0 end) as week,
       sum(case when cast(due_date as date) >= dateadd(month, -1, cast(getdate() as date)) then 1 else 0 end) as month
from t
group by typeid;
```

How to get the above described result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add TypeID inside the Sum and use Iteam ID in group by

```
select ITEM_ID,
   sum(case when cast(due_date as date) = cast(getdate() as date) and TYPE_ID = 1  then 1 else 0 end) as COUNT_TODAY_TYPE_1,
   sum(case when cast(due_date as date) = cast(getdate() as date) and TYPE_ID = 2  then 1 else 0 end) as COUNT_TODAY_TYPE_2,
   sum(case when cast(due_date as date) >= cast(getdate() - 7 as date)  and TYPE_ID = 1  then 1 else 0 end) as COUNT_ONEWEEK_TYPE_1,
   sum(case when cast(due_date as date) >= cast(getdate() - 7 as date)  and TYPE_ID = 2  then 1 else 0 end) as COUNT_ONEWEEK_TYPE_2,
   sum(case when cast(due_date as date) >= dateadd(month, -1, cast(getdate() as date)) and TYPE_ID = 1   then 1 else 0 end) as COUNT_ONEMONTH_TYPE_1,
   sum(case when cast(due_date as date) >= dateadd(month, -1, cast(getdate() as date)) and TYPE_ID = 2   then 1 else 0 end) as COUNT_ONEMONTH_TYPE_2
from t
group by ITEM_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
select * from
(
select TYPE_ID, 

       count(case when cast(due_date as date) = cast(getdate() as date) then 1 else NULL end) as COUNT_TODAY_TYPE_1,
       count(case when cast(due_date as date) >= cast(getdate() - 7 as date) then 1 else NULL end) as COUNT_week_TYPE_1,
       count(case when cast(due_date as date) >= dateadd(month, -1, cast(getdate() as date)) then 1 else NULL end) as COUNT_month_TYPE_1
from #A
where TYPE_ID='1'
group by TYPE_ID
)aa,
(
select TYPE_ID, 
       count(case when cast(due_date as date) = cast(getdate() as date) then 1 else NULL end) as COUNT_TODAY_TYPE_2,
       count(case when cast(due_date as date) >= cast(getdate() - 7 as date) then 1 else NULL end) as COUNT_ONEWEEK_TYPE_2,
       count(case when cast(due_date as date) >= dateadd(month, -1, cast(getdate() as date)) then 1 else NULL end) as COUNT_month_TYPE_2
from #A
where TYPE_ID='2'
group by TYPE_ID
)a
```

Using SELECT COUNT(*) or SELECT COUNT(1) (which is what I prefer to use) will return the total of all records returned in the result set regardless of NULL values.